# Allowing Domain Group to Administer IIS Server

Tags: active-directory, permissions, iis-8

I have a Windows 2012 server with IIS 8 on it.  I am trying to allow users within a IIS_ADMIN group on my Active Directory to be allowed to administer the server.

**The Problem**

When I log into my server with a user that is in the IIS_ADMIN group, and I open IIS, i am presented with the start page and only the start page.
[image]

I will then try to connect to the local server using the "Connect to a server..." option, I am presented with the error "Unauthorized.

I can log into the server as Administrator or a member of the administrator group and see the start page as well as the local server in IIS.

**The Expected Result**

I want to be able to add any user to the IIS_ADMIN group within my AD and have them be able to see the server when they log onto it and open IIS.

**What I have Tried**

I have tried a few different options here to try to solve this problem.

- Add AD group (IIS_ADMIN) to the IIS_USRS Local Group on the local group policy
- Add AD group (IIS_ADMIN) to the Administrator Group on the local server
- Added user of the IIS_ADMIN group to the Administrators Group on the local server (this works but **not** what I want because this would give User administrator access to the whole system)

Comment: Since you posted the answer in the question, add user to IIS_Admin, please describe further why this is not the solution needed.

Comment: @EdFries: because I dont want the IIS_ADMIN group to have administrator access to the whole computer.. ONLY iis

Comment: Adding a user to IIS_Admin group doesn't provide admin access to entire machine, unless the rights for the IIS_Admin group have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use IIS feature delegation to allow an IIS admin who is not also an admin of the entire server:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/an-overview-of-feature-delegation-in-iis

[image: IIS Feature Delegation]